# Как сделать компонент, который работает с несколькими типами в качестве входных параметров?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular

Хочу сделать компонент селектор, к которому можно привязать несколько определенных типов и каждый тип будет обрабатываться немного со своими нюансами при отображении/редактировании.

Например, есть тип SomeType  {id:number,name:string}, и я хочу разрешить биндить number[], либо SomeType[].

Сначала я пошел очевидным путем:
Создал поле `@Input()` SomeField с типом данных `number[]|SomeType[]` и поле `@Output() SomeFieldChange= new EventEmitter<number[]|SomeType[]>();`, но столкнулся с тем, что если мне будет передан пустой массив, то я никак не могу определить тип из-за природы JavaScript => верно выстроить логику.

Сейчас я решил эту задачу через ввод перечисления:

```
export enum InputType {
  Ids,
  SomeFields
}
```

и дополнительного поля `@Input() inputType: InputType;`

Однако, является это решение верным или есть другие лучшие пути?

Comment: 2 инпута сделайте

Comment: В этом есть смысл. Правда придется контроллить несколько полей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Angular не принято контролировать несколько типов в контексте одного байндинга, это попахивает спагетти, я, например, такого никогда не видел. Намного легче иметь несколько отдельных байндингов и контролировать этот поток данных (с родительского вниз к дочернему компоненту).

С другой стороны, если вы все же не хотите обрабатывать 2 байндинга, вам никто не мешает создать собственные коллекции:

```
export class NumberCollection extends Array<number> {}
export class SomeFieldCollection extends Array<SomeType> {}
```

Далее создать инстансы этих классов:

```
public numbers = new NumberCollection();
public someFields = new SomeFieldCollection();
```

Задать входным параметром:

```
[someField]="numbers"
// OR
[someField]="someFields"
```

Даже если массив пустой - вы можете сделать проверку, на то что объект принадлежит к определенному классу:

```
@Input()
public someField: NumberCollection | SomeFieldCollection;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  if (this.someField instanceof NumberCollection) {
    ...
  }

  if (this.someField instanceof SomeFieldCollection) {
    ...
  }
}
```

В другом случае - делайте 2 отдельных входных параметра.

Comment: Мож вы еще на это ответите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968726/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC-required?

Comment: и на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968448/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-typescript =)