# Подскажите, как наиболее верно производить приведение типов в TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Собственно вопрос, как наиболее верно производить приведение типов в `TypeScript`?

В нем присутствует `Type Assertion`, который фактически не делает никаких приведений, например, метод который есть в реальном объекте нельзя вызвать.

Неужели единственный путь, получив какой-нибудь JSON, как результат Http-запроса - это перебрать все поля, а затем если все сошлось, то выполнить `Object.Assing` к реально созданному объекту?

Comment: обычно результат JSON, описывают как интерфейс. Далее в нужном классе можно сделать конструктор принимающий объект с интерфейсом. и работать с данными внутри класса. Так как функций в json нет. Просто приведение не нужно.

Comment: А проверить то, что мне пришло в конструктор на предмет того, что это ожидаемый тип я должен через перебор полей?

Comment: не понял вопроса.

Comment: Ну например, есть класс Б. Вы сказали, что должен быть конструктор, который позволяет создать класс из JSON. Как я могу понять, что ко мне пришел ожидаемый мною тип? Перебором всех полей и если они меня удволитворяют, то создаю объект?

Comment: _Вы сказали, что должен быть конструктор, который позволяет создать класс из JSON._ - нет, я не это сказал, перечитай мое сообщение еще раз :)

Comment: @Grundy можете ответом оформить с примерами?=) А то, пока я мыслю строготипизированным подходом, а порядками в мире динамики еще не проникся.

Comment: У тебя твой подход и в строготипизированном походе не сработал бы: если тебе приходит object, в котором один класс лежит, а ты попытаешься получить из него другой класс - в большинстве языков будет какой-нибудь InvalidCastException

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14425568/4928642 2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33800497/4928642

Comment: @Grundy, и? При чём тут вообще другие языки?

Comment: @Qwertiy, при том, что то как он хочет = нигде не работает :-)

Comment: @Grundy не, ну если просто кастовать, то да, а если использовать какой-нибудь C#ий as, то либо тип приведется, либо вернется null и при желании можно кинуть исключение с описание проблемы.

Comment: @iluxa1810, `as` всегда будет возвращать `null`, так как ты не знаешь какой класс возвращает `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Grundy, десериализатор же исключение кинет, если там какая-то муть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему? Валидный json всегда распознается.

Comment: @Grundy, если тип не соответствует заявленному? Я про newtonsoft json.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, может кинуть. А может null вернуть или скорее просто поля некоторые заполнены не будут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Информация о типах существует только на этапе компиляции, поэтому проверить в рантайме соответствие объекта интерфейсу можно только написанным кодом.

Хотя можно не писать этот код самому, а воспользоваться одним из готовых модулей:

- https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-builder
- https://github.com/gristlabs/ts-interface-checker

Comment: Хорошо, допустим, я проверил тип из JSON на предмет наличия всех необходимых полей. Как я могу привести к реальному типу, что бы получить доступ к методам реального типа? С помощью конструктора реального типа, который принимает Any, а внутри копирует все по полям или через Object.Assing все автоматом скопировать в новый объект?

Comment: @iluxa1810 _Как я могу привести к реальному типу_ - никак. в js Нет механизма приведения типов, которые мог бы использовать в коде

Comment: @Grundy, хорошо давайте по другому =). Как я могу создать из JSON'а нормальный объект с прототипами и всем остальным, когда я убедился, что по полям все сходится? Только имея спец. конструктор в целевом типе или через Assign?

Comment: @iluxa1810, написать свой метод разбора json.

Comment: @Grundy ну это я и хотел услышать.