# Как сделать компонент с настраиваемым required?

Tags: angular2, angular

Допустим, компонент А представляет собой блок `input-ов`.

Этот компонент я добавляю внутрь другого компонента.

В компоненте Б заполняемость `input'ов` может быть обязательная, а в компоненте С нет.

В обычном случае, если бы не было компонента А и я добавлял бы поля напрямую в Б и С я бы пометил бы необходимые поля `required`, а затем повесил бы на кнопку условие, что поля валидны.

На ум приходит только передача через `@Input()` компонента А массива с названием необходимых полей и какое-нибудь булево `@Output()` свойство, которое может читать компонент Б при изменении компонента А, показывающие валидность.

Это правильное решение или есть другие более простые варианты?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Необязательно это делать через входные параметры, я часто предпочитаю взаимодействие через сервисы, изолируя бизнес логику, а также сервисы позволяют добавить щепотку производительности.

К тому же я бы предпочел оперировать константами. Angular построен таким образом, что он будет каждый раз проверять не изменилось ли входное свойство:

```
[requiredFields]="['name', 'surname']"
```

Хотя с другой стороны этот список должен быть константой. Поэтому здесь 2 варианта - использовать сервисы либо константные атрибуты.

Компонент `A` должен находиться в отдельное папке, если это какой-то переиспользуемый компонент и структура должна выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Еще если подключите TS `paths`, то получится мед, будут понятные и читабельные импорты. Компонент вы добавляете в `declarations` и `exports`, тем самым мы получаем так называемый "small&dumb" модуль. Сервис мы не объявляем в провайдерах этого модуля, сервис будет использоваться родительскими компонентами `B` и `C`, которые будут проджектить этот компонент `A`.

Сервис будет представлять из себя нечто подобное:

```
interface RequiredFieldsState {
  allFieldsRequired: boolean;
  requiredFields?: string[];
}

@Injectable()
export class RequiredFieldsService implements OnDestroy {
  private state$ = new BehaviorSubject<RequiredFieldsState>(null);

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.state$.complete();
  }

  public setState(state: RequiredFieldsState): void {
    this.state$.next(state);
  }

  public getSnapshot(): RequiredFieldsState {
    return this.state$.getValue();
  }
}
```

Сервис мы будем добавлять в провайдеры компонентов `B` и `C`:

```
import { RequiredFieldsService } from '@app/shared/A';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  template: `
    <app-a></app-a>
  `,
  providers: [RequiredFieldsService]
})
export class BComponent {}
```

У компонента `A` также должен быть доступ к инстансу сервиса `RequiredFieldsService`, также я еще хотел бы, чтоб Angular начал поиск зависимости с родительского инжектора и пропустил текущий:

```
import { SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

export class AComponent {
  constructor(
    @SkipSelf() private requiredFieldsService: RequiredFieldsService
  ) {}
}
```

В родительском компоненте вы просто вызываете метод `setState` сервиса с нужными параметрами:

```
import { RequiredFieldsService } from '@app/shared/A';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  template: `
    <app-a></app-a>
  `,
  providers: [RequiredFieldsService]
})
export class BComponent {
  constructor(
    @Self() requiredFieldsService: RequiredFieldsService
  ) {
    requiredFieldsService.setState({
      allFieldsRequired: false
    });
  }
}
```

Декоратор `@Self` говорит Angular получить зависимость для `BComponent` только из его собственного инжектора.

В `AComponent` вы получаете текущее состояние, проводите некоторые инициализации и сеттите атрибуты `required`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input name="name" placeholder="Имя" [required]="required">
      <input name="surname" placeholder="Фамилия" [required]="required">
    </form>
  `
})
export class AComponent {
  public required = this.requiredFieldsService.getSnapshot().allFieldsRequired;

  constructor(
    @SkipSelf() private requiredFieldsService: RequiredFieldsService
  ) {}
}
```

Если же мы хотим, чтобы 1 инпут был `required`, а второй нет, то соответственно сеттим состояние следующим образом:

```
requireFieldsService.setState({
  allFieldsRequired: false,
  requiredFields: ['name']
});
```

В самом сервисе `RequiredFieldsService` я бы создал такой хелпер метод:

```
public inputShouldBeRequired({ name }: HTMLInputElement): boolean {
  const { requiredFields } = this.getSnapshot();

  if (Array.isArray(requiredFields)) {
    return requiredFields.includes(name);
  }

  return false;
}
```

Использовал бы его в шаблоне следующим образом:

```
<input name="name" #name [required]="requiredFieldsService.inputShouldBeRequired(name)">
```

Как быть с константными атрибутами? Декоратор `@Attribute` позволяет получить доступ к ***строковому*** атрибуту, который биндится к элементу. Angular сеттит его 1 раз и забывает про него. Как использовать?

```
import { Attribute } from '@angular/core';

export class AComponent {
  constructor(
    @Attribute('requiredFields') requiredFields: string | null
  ) {}
}
```

Биндинг один в один как и входного свойства:

```
<app-a requiredFields="['name']"></app-a>
```

Квадратные скобки использовать нельзя, все что внутри кавычек - ***строка***!. Разница в том, что доступ в входным параметрам мы можем получить только в `ngOnChanges`, в отличии от атрибутов, которые доступны уже в конструкторе на этапе инициализации, потому что на этапе компиляции уже известно значение. Как нам превратить строку `['name']` в массив `required` инпутов - распарсить:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: `
    <form>
      <input name="name" #name [required]="inputShouldBeRequired(name)">
    </form>
  `
})
export class AComponent {
  public requiredFields: string[] = [];

  constructor(
    @Attribute('requiredFields') requiredFields: string | null
  ) {
    this.setRequireFields(requiredFields);
  }

  private setRequireFields(requiredFields: string | null): void {
    if (requiredFields === null) {
      return;
    }

    this.requiredFields = JSON.parse(requiredFields.replace(/\'/g, "\""));
  }

  public inputShouldBeRequired({ name }: HTMLInputElement): boolean {
    return this.requiredFields.includes(name);
  }
}
```

И кстати во втором варианте нам не нужен сервис, мы засеттили `requiredFields` 1 раз на этапе инициализации и забыли про него, тем самым Angular не будет производить какие либо проверки.

Comment: @SkipSelf() , а разве итак не скипнется поиск, если не указывать в провайдерах?

Comment: Ну и в примере еще не вижу проброс родительскому компоненту информации о прохождении валидности, что бы потом родительский компонент по итогам валидность, разблокировал какую-нибудь кнопку отправления формы.

Comment: А почему используете именно BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: @iluxa1810 1. нет 2. вопрос звучит `Как сделать компонент с настраиваемым required?` + вы это можете реализовать сами 3. широковещательные потоки всегда можно отслеживать по желанию, в отличии от обычных переменных